# How to take input from other programs

Tags: python

First program:

```
import destinations
import currency

main_function = True
while (main_function):

def main():

    # Determine length of stay
    while True:
        try:
            length_of_stay = int(input("And how many days will you be staying in " + destination + "? "))
            # Check for non-positive input
            if (length_of_stay <= 0):
                print("Please enter a positive number of days.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numerical values are valid.")
        else:
            break
```

Second program:

```
def get_choice():
# Get destination choice
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("Where would you like to go? "))
        if (choice < 1 or choice > 3):
            print("Please select a choice between 1 and 3.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numerical values are valid.")
    else:
        return choice

choice = get_choice()

def get_info(choice):
# Use numeric choice to look up destination info
# Rates are listed in euros per day

    # Choice 1: Rome at €45/day
    if (choice == 1):
        return "Rome", 45


    # Choice 2: Berlin at €18/day
    elif (choice == 2):
        return "Berlin", 18

    # Choice 3: Vienna, €34/day
    elif (choice == 3):
        return "Vienna", 34

destination = get_info(choice)
```

Problem: First program runs with an error after input:
"NameError: name 'destination' is not defined"

Question: How is it that adding  `destination = get_info(choice)`    doesn't count as defining     `destination`    ?
What can I do to get the first program to agree with the input from the second program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import destinations` will run the module with that name, which should be on the PythonPath (otherwise it will raise an `ImportError`). So that's good. Once that file is run, all variables, functions, classes that were defined in it are accessible under the namespace `destinations`.

So in the file called `destinations.py`, if there is a variable called `destination` (which you made on the last line of file2), then you can access it as `destinations.destination` from within the first file (or any file that has the import statement `import destinations`).

You can read up on the different ways of importing items from different modules over at [effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm). It will teach you that another attractive alternative for you would've been to write

```
from destinations import destination
```

and then your first file will work normally.

Note that the code you've copied here seems to have some indentation issues. Furthermore, you'll want to write (in the first file) `destination[0]` each time you need the word ("Rome", "Berlin", ..), because your function `get_info` from the 2nd file (`destinations.py`), returns a tuple (e.g. `("Rome", 45)`. You'll get a `TypeError` if you don't take that into account.

Comment: So then, using `destinations.XXX` will use whatever input I've designated in the program; same with my other program, currency, but just `currency.XXX`?

I've added `destination = 0` and have `...+destinations.destination+...` and I did come up with the `TypeError`. What is a tuple? How do I fix this error?

Comment: @sithlorddahlia, yes, when you import a module using the `import some_module` statement, you can access everything from that module by typing `some_module.some_variable_or_func`. Don't add `destination=0` anywhere, your 2nd file is fine as it is (ignoring the indentation errors). A [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) is one of Python's elementary datastructures. The only real change to your posted code would be to replace `+ destination +` to `+ destinations.destination[0] +` to get your code to work.

Comment: Life saver! Thank you, Oliver!

Comment: @sithlorddahlia No problem, glad to have helped and to have found a relatively new user of Stackoverflow that knows how SO works. Thanks for accepting.